# Category Tracking with MarketingCloudSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, android, salesforce-sdk-android

The MarketingCloudSDK (iOS/Android) offers the method
`sfmc_trackPageView` with an `item` parameter, but how would I track the category?

It works in the Web SDK or API, this is about what I miss in the SDK:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_track_category_view.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is available on the reporting side once items are sent, but that method should be overloaded and except `url`, `title`, `item` and `searchTerms`: Android: `sdk.analyticsManager.trackPageView("url", "title", "item", "searchTerms")` (ref. [Analytics Android](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/analytics/analytics.html#track-page-views) and [Analytics iOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/analytics/personalization-collect.html#track-page-views))

Aside from that, you should open a Voice of Customer (VoC) request through your account executive.  It is requests like this that are required to get features on the roadmap.

Comment: The function I mentioned is exactly that, I quoted only the name in the iOS SDK though, sorry. So yes, this is the method that I'd LIKE to use, however an explicit category parameter is missing. I wondered if I oversee some different way but to use the Web version of the Collect API (which works).

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the only viable answer - at least on iOS - for now, it has been confirmed to be not available yet, however there is an existing VoC already, thanks you.

Comment: IDK how VoC requests work, but the more the merrier ;)